# How do I view or rename a file with missing extension?

Tags: file, rename, explorer

I have a strange file in my file system without the extension part.  The filename is "15.".  The weird thing is that it is not one of those without the dot part (like just "15"), but the one with the dot but no extension ("15.") -- it is literally an illegal filename in windows, and not sure how did it get created in the first place.

I know it is a text file and it is about 15KB in size; however, due to the weirdness in name, I can't open it with any application -- I've tried to open in notepad, wordpad, etc., have tried the 'type' command to spit it out on commans shell, tried to shell-open enclosing filename in quotes, and so on -- all methods result in a 'file not found' error except the notepad, which says '15.txt' is not found.

Due to the nature of the issue and the way search engines optimize the search, it is extemely hard to search for an answer in any of the search engines online.  So, I just wanted to put this question out there and see if anybody had to deal with a similar issue and have found any way to rename the file or even to change the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filenames that are valid in NTFS but cannot be used from Windows can be created when accesing disks or shares from other operating systems like Linux.

If you don't have a Linux installation at hand, then get hold of a *"live"* CD, boot Linux, and change the filename.

That may sound like a hassle, but Windows-only solutions (moving stuff around, deleting the directory) are even worse.

Comment: That might work actually; will try that next.  I just wanted to ensure there is no easy (windows) solition to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use REN: http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html

It is a command prompt command (run > cmd > cd wherever > ren 15. 15.txt )

Comment: That won't work - 15. is not a valid filename as far as any windows os commands are concerned!  It fails at the Kernel level trying to get a handler to the file -- so no usual/easy things would work I guess.